# How do you call different javascript functions dependent on which radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to call different javascript functions to run in my html from the selection of radio buttons. I currently have 3 buttons and I want them to run after a button is clicked.

My current HTML is:

```
<button class="button" onclick="runScript();">Run</button>

<input name="radioButton" type="radio" value="1"> Option 1
<input name="radioButton" type="radio" value="2"> Option 2
<input name="radioButton" type="radio" value="3"> Option 3
```

I want all 3 options to run separate functions, such as if value="1" then run function 1, etc. It's not a lot but as for my javascript I currently have:

```
function runScript() {
    var x = document.getElementsByName("radioButton").value;
}
```

Any ideas on how I can get the functions to run like this?

Comment: `switch ($(":radio[name=radioButton]:checked").val())`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Barmar could you give me a little more context about this?

Comment: What more do you need to know? Inside the switch you can use `case "1": func1(); break; case "2": func2(); ...`

Comment: I didn't even know about switch, where would I put that in my code?

Comment: That's basic JavaScript syntax.

Comment: It's like a series of `if` statements, so you put it where you would have put an `if` statement to call the function you want.

Comment: See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_switch_case.htm

Comment: So it would be something like this? `function runScript { switch ($(":radio[name=radioButton]:checked").val(1)) case "1": func1();`

Comment: `.val(1)` is for setting the value. If you want to get the value use just `.val()` like I showed above and like in the duplicate function.

Comment: `function runScript() { switch ($(":radio[name=radioButton]:checked").val()) { case "1": func1(); break; case "2": func2(); break; case "3": func3(); break; } }`

Answer (score 0):

You could get the value of the selected item with a line like this:

```
var x = document.querySelector('input[name="radioButton"]:checked').value
```

instead of:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("radioButton").value;
```

That being said, I would generally not access value until you're sure your query selector found anything, or you'll get an exception.

Comment: You're missing `.value`

Comment: thanks.. I'd probably not check the value right where I do the querySelector, but for the sake of the example, it's true.. really we should check if the querySelector found anything, and then get the value.

Comment: Using jQuery would make it shorter and also avoid the error of trying to get the property of null.

Comment: I'd found my way to the question through the javascript tag and didn't realize it was a jquery question until you just pointed that out. oops. I prefer straight js, but contextually you're right. My bad.